# iterate over a multidimensional array and print all possibility

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i try to iterate over a multidimensional array to print all possible choice.
I dont understand why i cant print the second params2 from the first array with all params in my second multidimensional array . 
i cant see where is my mistake on my code :(

```
array=[["params1","params2"],["params3","params4"]]

    i = 0
    j = 0 

          while i <= 2       
            res0 = array[0][i]
               i +=1

            while j <= 1
                res1 = array[1][j]
                 j +=1

              puts "res0 =#{res0} res1 =#{res1} "
            end
          end
```

The result when i execute my code .

```
res0 =params1 res1 = params3 
res0 =params1 res2 = params4
```

what i would want it's

```
res0 =params1 res1 = params3 
res0 =params1 res2 = params4
res0 =params2 res1 = params3 
res0 =params2 res2 = params4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use built in methods for this.

```
array.first.product(array.last).each{ |a| puts "res0 =#{a.first} res1 =#{a.last} "}
```

Comment: thank i didn't know that methods ;)

Comment: and if you have a  three nultidimensional array array=[["params1","params2"],["params3","params4"],["params5","params6"]]

Comment: what have you tryed?